# Find the power series of $\ln^{2}(1-x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the power series for $\ln^{2}(1-x)$ without directly using the Taylor's series to expand it.

I am thinking about Taylor expand $\ln(1-x)$ but have no idea on what to do next.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply two power series?

Comment: Multiplying term by term?

Comment: That's right. You should be able to express the $x^n$ coefficient in terms of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), as $\frac2nH_{n-1}$ for $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $|x|<1$
Let,
$$f(x)=\ln^{2}(1-x)$$
Then,
$$f'(x)=\frac{2\ln(1-x)}{x-1}$$
Now we already know that,
$$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$
Use that fact here,
$$f'(x)=-\frac{2}{x-1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k}$$
Integral on both sides from $0$ to $u$, where $|u|<1$(Because the range of $x$ was $[-1,1)$)
Now the LHS of the equation will be $f(u)$ and on the right hand side we get a series expansion of it. I will leave the evaluation part to the reader.